# Formatted capacity of a Sandisk Fusion-IO Card?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, ntfs, formatting, fusionio

I'm interested in buying some 6.4 TB [Fusion IO SX300](http://www.fusionio.com/data-sheets/iomemory-sx300-atomic-series) cards. They will be formatted as NTFS 64 Kb cluster size with Windows Server. My question is what will the actual usable space be once the drives are formatted with a filesystem on top? Does anyone have some of these and have formatted them for Windows Server?

Comment: I don't see how those SSD are supposed to be different from any other SSD/HDD/RAID/iSCSI/whtever solution as far as NTFS is concerned. Can you clarify?

Comment: I'd call Fusion-io.

Comment: I did, they said 5.81 TB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I called Fusion IO and they said 5.81 TB.

Answer (score 1):

This'll depend on the cluster size you're using and the average size of the files you're putting on it (more files = more overhead, generally).

From my experience with comparable disk sizes,  the overhead is negligble.

Comment: I edited my question to include the cluster size. Once the drive is formatted I want to know what Windows will report as usable space in GB.